Version requirements for Deep Learning Libraries of ArcGIS in Google Colab
I have been using ArcGIS's EntityRecognizer for some time now. I train the model on Google Colab as it provides faster runtime(GPU enabled).
As you know Google Colab now has updated its runtime to Python 3.10 from Python 3.7.
Hence the deep learning libraries that was working for 3.7 are not working for 3.10.
For example in Python 3.7 we were using arcgis==1.8.4 torch==1.4.0 and torchvision==0.5.0 etc.
But now arcgis version has also updated for 3.10 to arcgis==2.0.0. Correspondingly it has different deep learning libraries version.
I have tried doing
!pip install arcgis[torch]

in order to download individually all the libraries but there seems to be some mismatch as it is giving me the following error:

Here is my libraries. As you can see fastai is already installed.
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- ---------------------
absl-py                          1.4.0
aiofiles                         22.1.0
aiohttp                          3.8.6
aiosignal                        1.3.1
aiosqlite                        0.19.0
alabaster                        0.7.13
albumentations                   1.3.1
altair                           4.2.2
anyio                            3.7.1
appdirs                          1.4.4
arcgis                           2.2.0.1
argon2-cffi                      23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings             21.2.0
array-record                     0.5.0
arrow                            1.3.0
arviz                            0.15.1
astropy                          5.3.4
astunparse                       1.6.3
async-timeout                    4.0.3
atpublic                         4.0
attrs                            23.1.0
audioread                        3.0.1
autograd                         1.6.2
Babel                            2.13.1
backcall                         0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                   4.11.2
bidict                           0.22.1
bigframes                        0.12.0
bleach                           6.1.0
blinker                          1.4
blis                             0.7.11
blosc2                           2.0.0
bokeh                            3.3.0
bqplot                           0.12.42
branca                           0.7.0
build                            1.0.3
CacheControl                     0.13.1
cachetools                       5.3.2
catalogue                        2.0.10
certifi                          2023.7.22
cffi                             1.16.0
chardet                          5.2.0
charset-normalizer               3.3.2
chex                             0.1.7
click                            8.1.7
click-plugins                    1.1.1
cligj                            0.7.2
cloudpickle                      2.2.1
cmake                            3.27.7
cmdstanpy                        1.2.0
colorcet                         3.0.1
colorlover                       0.3.0
colour                           0.1.5
community                        1.0.0b1
confection                       0.1.3
cons                             0.4.6
contextlib2                      21.6.0
contourpy                        1.2.0
cryptography                     41.0.5
cufflinks                        0.17.3
cupy-cuda11x                     11.0.0
cvxopt                           1.3.2
cvxpy                            1.3.2
cycler                           0.12.1
cymem                            2.0.8
Cython                           3.0.5
dask                             2023.8.1
datascience                      0.17.6
db-dtypes                        1.1.1
dbus-python                      1.2.18
debugpy                          1.6.6
decorator                        4.4.2
defusedxml                       0.7.1
diskcache                        5.6.3
distributed                      2023.8.1
distro                           1.7.0
dlib                             19.24.2
dm-tree                          0.1.8
docutils                         0.18.1
dopamine-rl                      4.0.6
duckdb                           0.9.1
earthengine-api                  0.1.377
easydict                         1.11
ecos                             2.0.12
editdistance                     0.6.2
eerepr                           0.0.4
en-core-web-sm                   3.6.0
entrypoints                      0.4
et-xmlfile                       1.1.0
etils                            1.5.2
etuples                          0.3.9
exceptiongroup                   1.1.3
fastai                           2.7.13
fastcore                         1.5.29
fastdownload                     0.0.7
fastjsonschema                   2.18.1
fastprogress                     1.0.3
fastrlock                        0.8.2
filelock                         3.13.1
fiona                            1.9.5
firebase-admin                   5.3.0
Flask                            2.2.5
flatbuffers                      23.5.26
flax                             0.7.5
folium                           0.14.0
fonttools                        4.44.0
fqdn                             1.5.1
frozendict                       2.3.8
frozenlist                       1.4.0
fsspec                           2023.6.0
future                           0.18.3
gast                             0.5.4
gcsfs                            2023.6.0
GDAL                             3.4.3
gdown                            4.6.6
geemap                           0.28.2
gensim                           4.3.2
geocoder                         1.38.1
geographiclib                    2.0
geomet                           1.0.0
geopandas                        0.13.2
geopy                            2.3.0
gin-config                       0.5.0
glob2                            0.7
google                           2.0.3
google-api-core                  2.11.1
google-api-python-client         2.84.0
google-auth                      2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2             0.1.1
google-auth-oauthlib             1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery            3.12.0
google-cloud-bigquery-connection 1.12.1
google-cloud-bigquery-storage    2.22.0
google-cloud-core                2.3.3
google-cloud-datastore           2.15.2
google-cloud-firestore           2.11.1
google-cloud-functions           1.13.3
google-cloud-iam                 2.12.2
google-cloud-language            2.9.1
google-cloud-resource-manager    1.10.4
google-cloud-storage             2.8.0
google-cloud-translate           3.11.3
google-colab                     1.0.0
google-crc32c                    1.5.0
google-pasta                     0.2.0
google-resumable-media           2.6.0
googleapis-common-protos         1.61.0
googledrivedownloader            0.4
graphviz                         0.20.1
greenlet                         3.0.1
grpc-google-iam-v1               0.12.6
grpcio                           1.59.2
grpcio-status                    1.48.2
gspread                          3.4.2
gspread-dataframe                3.3.1
gssapi                           1.8.3
gym                              0.25.2
gym-notices                      0.0.8
h5netcdf                         1.3.0
h5py                             3.9.0
holidays                         0.36
holoviews                        1.17.1
html5lib                         1.1
httpimport                       1.3.1
httplib2                         0.22.0
huggingface-hub                  0.19.0
humanize                         4.7.0
hyperopt                         0.2.7
ibis-framework                   6.2.0
idna                             3.4
imageio                          2.31.6
imageio-ffmpeg                   0.4.9
imagesize                        1.4.1
imbalanced-learn                 0.10.1
imgaug                           0.4.0
importlib-metadata               6.8.0
importlib-resources              6.1.1
imutils                          0.5.4
inflect                          7.0.0
iniconfig                        2.0.0
install                          1.3.5
intel-openmp                     2023.2.0
ipyevents                        2.0.2
ipyfilechooser                   0.6.0
ipykernel                        5.5.6
ipyleaflet                       0.17.4
ipython                          7.34.0
ipython-genutils                 0.2.0
ipython-sql                      0.5.0
ipytree                          0.2.2
ipywidgets                       7.7.1
isoduration                      20.11.0
itsdangerous                     2.1.2
jax                              0.4.20
jaxlib                           0.4.20+cuda11.cudnn86
jedi                             0.19.1
jeepney                          0.7.1
jieba                            0.42.1
Jinja2                           3.1.2
joblib                           1.3.2
json5                            0.9.14
jsonpickle                       3.0.2
jsonpointer                      2.4
jsonschema                       4.19.2
jsonschema-specifications        2023.7.1
jupyter-client                   6.1.12
jupyter-console                  6.1.0
jupyter_core                     5.5.0
jupyter-events                   0.9.0
jupyter-server                   1.24.0
jupyter_server_fileid            0.9.0
jupyter_server_ydoc              0.8.0
jupyter-ydoc                     0.2.5
jupyterlab                       3.6.6
jupyterlab-pygments              0.2.2
jupyterlab_server                2.25.1
jupyterlab-widgets               3.0.9
kaggle                           1.5.16
keras                            2.14.0
keyring                          23.5.0
kiwisolver                       1.4.5
krb5                             0.5.1
langcodes                        3.3.0
launchpadlib                     1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient               0.14.4
lazr.uri                         1.0.6
lazy_loader                      0.3
libclang                         16.0.6
librosa                          0.10.1
lida                             0.0.10
lightgbm                         4.1.0
linkify-it-py                    2.0.2
llmx                             0.0.15a0
llvmlite                         0.41.1
locket                           1.0.0
logical-unification              0.4.6
lxml                             4.9.3
malloy                           2023.1064
Markdown                         3.5.1
markdown-it-py                   3.0.0
MarkupSafe                       2.1.3
matplotlib                       3.7.1
matplotlib-inline                0.1.6
matplotlib-venn                  0.11.9
mdit-py-plugins                  0.4.0
mdurl                            0.1.2
miniKanren                       1.0.3
missingno                        0.5.2
mistune                          0.8.4
mizani                           0.9.3
mkl                              2023.2.0
ml-dtypes                        0.2.0
mlxtend                          0.22.0
more-itertools                   10.1.0
moviepy                          1.0.3
mpmath                           1.3.0
msgpack                          1.0.7
multidict                        6.0.4
multipledispatch                 1.0.0
multitasking                     0.0.11
murmurhash                       1.0.10
music21                          9.1.0
natsort                          8.4.0
nbclassic                        1.0.0
nbclient                         0.9.0
nbconvert                        6.5.4
nbformat                         5.9.2
nest-asyncio                     1.5.8
networkx                         3.2.1
nibabel                          4.0.2
nltk                             3.8.1
notebook                         6.5.5
notebook_shim                    0.2.3
numba                            0.58.1
numexpr                          2.8.7
numpy                            1.23.5
oauth2client                     4.1.3
oauthlib                         3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python            4.8.0.76
opencv-python                    4.8.0.76
opencv-python-headless           4.8.1.78
openpyxl                         3.1.2
opt-einsum                       3.3.0
optax                            0.1.7
orbax-checkpoint                 0.4.2
osqp                             0.6.2.post8
packaging                        23.2
pandas                           2.1.2
pandas-datareader                0.10.0
pandas-gbq                       0.17.9
pandas-stubs                     1.5.3.230304
pandocfilters                    1.5.0
panel                            1.3.1
param                            2.0.0
parso                            0.8.3
parsy                            2.1
partd                            1.4.1
pathlib                          1.0.1
pathy                            0.10.3
patsy                            0.5.3
peewee                           3.17.0
pexpect                          4.8.0
pickleshare                      0.7.5
Pillow                           9.4.0
pip                              23.1.2
pip-tools                        6.13.0
platformdirs                     3.11.0
plotly                           5.15.0
plotnine                         0.12.4
pluggy                           1.3.0
polars                           0.17.3
pooch                            1.8.0
portpicker                       1.5.2
prefetch-generator               1.0.3
preshed                          3.0.9
prettytable                      3.9.0
proglog                          0.1.10
progressbar2                     4.2.0
prometheus-client                0.18.0
promise                          2.3
prompt-toolkit                   3.0.39
prophet                          1.1.5
proto-plus                       1.22.3
protobuf                         3.20.3
psutil                           5.9.5
psycopg2                         2.9.9
ptyprocess                       0.7.0
py-cpuinfo                       9.0.0
py4j                             0.10.9.7
pyarrow                          9.0.0
pyasn1                           0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                   0.3.0
pycocotools                      2.0.7
pycparser                        2.21
pyct                             0.5.0
pydantic                         1.10.13
pydata-google-auth               1.8.2
pydot                            1.4.2
pydot-ng                         2.0.0
pydotplus                        2.0.2
PyDrive                          1.3.1
PyDrive2                         1.6.3
pyerfa                           2.0.1.1
pygame                           2.5.2
Pygments                         2.16.1
PyGObject                        3.42.1
PyJWT                            2.3.0
pylerc                           4.0
pymc                             5.7.2
pymystem3                        0.2.0
PyOpenGL                         3.1.7
pyOpenSSL                        23.3.0
pyparsing                        3.1.1
pyperclip                        1.8.2
pyproj                           3.6.1
pyproject_hooks                  1.0.0
pyshp                            2.3.1
PySocks                          1.7.1
pyspnego                         0.10.2
pytensor                         2.14.2
pytest                           7.4.3
python-apt                       0.0.0
python-box                       7.1.1
python-dateutil                  2.8.2
python-json-logger               2.0.7
python-louvain                   0.16
python-slugify                   8.0.1
python-utils                     3.8.1
pytz                             2023.3.post1
pyviz_comms                      3.0.0
PyWavelets                       1.4.1
PyYAML                           6.0.1
pyzmq                            23.2.1
qdldl                            0.1.7.post0
qudida                           0.0.4
ratelim                          0.1.6
referencing                      0.30.2
regex                            2023.6.3
requests                         2.31.0
requests-gssapi                  1.2.3
requests-kerberos                0.14.0
requests-oauthlib                1.3.1
requests-toolbelt                1.0.0
requirements-parser              0.5.0
rfc3339-validator                0.1.4
rfc3986-validator                0.1.1
rich                             13.6.0
rpds-py                          0.12.0
rpy2                             3.4.2
rsa                              4.9
safetensors                      0.4.0
scikit-image                     0.19.3
scikit-learn                     1.2.2
scipy                            1.11.3
scooby                           0.9.2
scs                              3.2.3
seaborn                          0.12.2
SecretStorage                    3.3.1
Send2Trash                       1.8.2
setuptools                       67.7.2
shapely                          2.0.2
six                              1.16.0
sklearn-pandas                   2.2.0
smart-open                       6.4.0
sniffio                          1.3.0
snowballstemmer                  2.2.0
sortedcontainers                 2.4.0
soundfile                        0.12.1
soupsieve                        2.5
soxr                             0.3.7
spacy                            3.6.1
spacy-legacy                     3.0.12
spacy-loggers                    1.0.5
Sphinx                           5.0.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp          1.0.7
sphinxcontrib-devhelp            1.0.5
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp           2.0.4
sphinxcontrib-jsmath             1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp             1.0.6
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml    1.1.9
SQLAlchemy                       2.0.23
sqlglot                          17.16.2
sqlparse                         0.4.4
srsly                            2.4.8
stanio                           0.3.0
statsmodels                      0.14.0
sympy                            1.12
tables                           3.8.0
tabulate                         0.9.0
tbb                              2021.10.0
tblib                            3.0.0
tenacity                         8.2.3
tensorboard                      2.14.1
tensorboard-data-server          0.7.2
tensorflow                       2.14.0
tensorflow-datasets              4.9.3
tensorflow-estimator             2.14.0
tensorflow-gcs-config            2.14.0
tensorflow-hub                   0.15.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem     0.34.0
tensorflow-metadata              1.14.0
tensorflow-probability           0.22.0
tensorstore                      0.1.45
termcolor                        2.3.0
terminado                        0.17.1
text-unidecode                   1.3
textblob                         0.17.1
tf-slim                          1.1.0
thinc                            8.1.12
threadpoolctl                    3.2.0
tifffile                         2023.9.26
timm                             0.9.10
tinycss2                         1.2.1
toml                             0.10.2
tomli                            2.0.1
toolz                            0.12.0
torch                            2.1.0+cu118
torchaudio                       2.1.0+cu118
torchdata                        0.7.0
torchsummary                     1.5.1
torchtext                        0.16.0
torchvision                      0.16.0+cu118
tornado                          6.3.2
tqdm                             4.66.1
traitlets                        5.7.1
traittypes                       0.2.1
triton                           2.1.0
truststore                       0.8.0
tweepy                           4.14.0
typer                            0.9.0
types-python-dateutil            2.8.19.14
types-pytz                       2023.3.1.1
types-setuptools                 68.2.0.0
typing_extensions                4.5.0
tzdata                           2023.3
tzlocal                          5.2
uc-micro-py                      1.0.2
ujson                            5.8.0
uri-template                     1.3.0
uritemplate                      4.1.1
urllib3                          2.0.7
vega-datasets                    0.9.0
wadllib                          1.3.6
wasabi                           1.1.2
wcwidth                          0.2.9
webcolors                        1.13
webencodings                     0.5.1
websocket-client                 1.6.4
Werkzeug                         3.0.1
wheel                            0.41.3
widgetsnbextension               3.6.6
wordcloud                        1.9.2
wrapt                            1.14.1
xarray                           2023.7.0
xarray-einstats                  0.6.0
xgboost                          2.0.1
xlrd                             2.0.1
xxhash                           3.4.1
xyzservices                      2023.10.1
y-py                             0.6.2
yarl                             1.9.2
yellowbrick                      1.5
yfinance                         0.2.31
ypy-websocket                    0.8.4
zict                             3.0.0
zipp                             3.17.0

I have asked the arcgis team also the same question a year back and yet to receive any response.
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/1634
My question is

Has anyone used the EntityRecognizer in the current Colab environment?
What are the deep learning libraries versions you have used?

Added info: Since anyone might ask why not use Python 3.7 on local CPU to do the task - I am doing that currently but with more added data it is getting quite difficult.
Also I have visited the page they have mentioned in the error syntax. They also have not updated the page to provide the relevant libraries.
